# Getting a 'line background color pattern' on Bash

Tags: bash, usability, graphical-interaction

I use gnome terminal / Bash on Ubuntu 18.04 (the default one).

When I get some command outputs with several long lines after each other, my eye has difficulty to follow which line some later column belong to.

One good solution to avoid this problem is to use a line-based background color pattern, for example I would do the following in LibreOffice

[image]

Is there a way to get something similar in Bash? I.e. to get on bash a user-parametrizable alternating background color on a line basis? I looked for it quite extensively but did not find any resources so far.

## Edit 1

Opened an issue there asking for feature: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/issues/175

Comment: This would actually be a good feature for a terminal emulator, I really liked the idea. Maybe you should request such a feature from gnome-terminal (or whatever terminal you're using) developers, implementing this with shell features/utilities doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: Ok, thank you for the support and recommendation :) I will wait a day or so to see if somethings pops up here, if not I will open an issue on their repo as you recommend :)

Comment: Posted there: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/issues/175

Comment: Gnome terminal supports background images (https://askubuntu.com/questions/797418/how-to-set-a-image-as-background-of-the-gnome-terminal).  You could create a custom background image with the line highlighting pattern you want and just use that.